# Node.js, как читать с помощью readdir файлы, в названии которых есть русские буквы?

Tags: node.js

В каталоге лежат файлы с названиями, состоящими из русских букв. Когда делаю `readdir` то в колбеке приходят названия файлов, в которых русские буквы заменены на вопросительные знаки `?`. Как быть?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback
Так options.encoding вроде есть

Comment: Пишу вот так var files = fs.readdirSync('/nodewebkit/pub/Nrd',{encoding: 'windows-1251'}); Не получается. пробовал win1251

Comment: Хм, по всей видимости нода из коробки 1251 не поддерживает. Тогда вам надо принять то что придет как буфер (encoding: 'buffer') и прогнать черзе сторонний модуль перекодировки. Модули искать в npm по запросу "iconv" и брать что заработает и понравится